Jupyter Notebook: "Fatal error in launcher: unable to create process using..." after changing folder name
I recently changed the name of the parent folder holding the "Scripts" directory for my Python installation, and it appears to be causing some issues. This is in Windows.
For some background, I have a Python script that I am attempting to run using an Execute Process Task in SSIS, which was throwing an error. After some research and debugging, I realized it was because the path to the script and to my Python executable had a space in the name, which SSIS cannot handle. So I changed it from "SSIS Packages" to "SSISPackages". I also updated the PATH variable in my environment variables to show the updated folder name.
However, when I try to run jupyter notebook from the command line, I get an error saying "Fatal error in launcher: unable to create process using '"C:\SSIS Packages\python.exe" "C:\SSISPackages\Scripts\jupyter.exe" notebook': the system cannot find the file specified
As you can see, the jupyter.exe is being searched for in the updated location, but the python.exe path still shows the old folder name.
Could anybody provide guidance on where I can update how it goes about looking for the python.exe?
I am also unable to run pip install for the same reason, although pip can be accessed by running python -m pip install which I used to re-install Jupyter Notebook. However that did not alleviate the issue.
Please let me know in the comments if anything is unclear, or if any additional information should be included and I will update my question.
Thanks in advance!
